# Python multiline regex delimiter

Tags: python, regex, multiline, multilinestring

Having this multiline variable:

```
raw = '''
CONTENT = ALL
TABLES = TEST.RAW_1
        , TEST.RAW_2
        , TEST.RAW_3
        , TEST.RAW_4
PARALLEL = 4
'''
```

The structure is always `TAG = CONTENT`, both strings are NOT fixed  and `CONTENT` could contain new lines.

I need a **`regex`** to get:

```
[('CONTENT', 'ALL'), ('TABLES', 'TEST.RAW_1\n        , TEST.RAW_2\n        , TEST.RAW_3\n        , TEST.RAW_4\n'), ('PARALLEL', '4')]
```

Tried multiple combinations but I'm not able  to *stop* the `regex` *engine* at the right point for `TABLES` tag as its content is a *multiline string* delimited by the next tag.

Some *attempts* from the interpreter:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(\w+?)\s=\s(.+?)', raw, re.DOTALL)
[('CONTENT', 'A'), ('TABLES', 'T'), ('PARALLEL', '4')]


>>> re.findall(r'^(\w+)\s=\s(.+)?', raw, re.M)
[('CONTENT', 'ALL'), ('TABLES', 'TEST.RAW_1'), ('PARALLEL', '4')]


>>> re.findall(r'(\w+)\s=\s(.+)?', raw, re.DOTALL)
[('CONTENT', 'ALL\nTABLES = TEST.RAW_1\n        , TEST.RAW_2\n        , TEST.RAW_3\n        , TEST.RAW_4\nPARALLEL = 4\n')]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead to make sure you lazily match the value correctly:

```
(\w+)\s=\s(.+?)(?=$|\n[A-Z])
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

To be used with a DOTALL modifier so that a `.` could match a newline symbol. The `(?=$|\n[A-Z])` lookahead will require `.+?` to match up to the end of string, or up to the newline followed with an uppercase letter.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dP0wM5/2).

And alternative, faster regex (as it is an unrolled version of the expression above) - but DOTALL modifier should NOT be used with it:

```
(\w+)\s*=\s*(.*(?:\n(?![A-Z]).*)*)
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dP0wM5/3)

**Explanation**:

- `(\w+)` - Group 1 capturing 1+ word chars
- `\s*=\s*` - a `=` symbol wrapped with optional (0+) whitespaces
- `(.*(?:\n(?![A-Z]).*)*)` - Group 2 capturing 0+ sequences of:

  - `.*` - any 0+ characters other than a newline
  - `(?:\n(?![A-Z]).*)*` - 0+ sequences of:

    - `\n(?![A-Z])` -  a newline symbol not followed with an uppercase ASCII letter
    - `.*`  - any 0+ characters other than a newline

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/PMdsd1):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(\w+)\s=\s(.+?)(?=$|\n[A-Z])', re.DOTALL)
raw = '''
CONTENT = ALL
TABLES = TEST.RAW_1
        , TEST.RAW_2
        , TEST.RAW_3
        , TEST.RAW_4
PARALLEL = 4
'''
print(p.findall(raw))
```

Comment: Amazing explanation! Enormous `regex` *kung-fu* ..  Many thanks Wiktor!